# How to find the value of this indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I want to ask about this problem. This problem is simple and I've already found the answer, but when I'm checked at wolfram, my solution is different with it.

Here's the problem:

Find the value of 
$$ \int \frac{1-\sqrt{3x+2}}{1+\sqrt{3x+2}}dx $$ ?

First of all, I need to make a substitution, in this case I use u as the substitutor.

Then, suppose $$ u= \sqrt{3x+2}$$

So,  $$ u^2 = 3x+2 $$

$$ 2u\,\mathrm du = 3\,\mathrm dx $$

$$ \mathrm dx = \frac{2u\,\mathrm du}{3} $$

And the equation change to:

$$ \int \frac{(1-u)(2u)}{(1+u)(3)}\,\mathrm du $$

I simplify it to get:

$$ \frac{2}{3} \int \frac{u-u^2}{1+u}\,\mathrm du$$

Then I calculate it and get:

$$\frac23\left\{-\frac{u^2}2 +2u-2\ln|u+1|\right\}+C $$

And for the last, I substitute back the value of u to my answer to get:

$$-x-\frac23 +\frac{4\sqrt{3x+2}}{3}-\frac{4\ln|\sqrt{3x+2}+1|}{3}+ C $$

But, when I'm checking wolfram, the solution is not same.  The constant is different.

[Here's the wolfram solution](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-%E2%88%9A%283x%2B2%29%29%2F%281%2B%E2%88%9A%283x%2B2%29%29).

I don't know where is my mistake. Can someone try to correct my mistake for this problem?  Thanks

Comment: The constant is arbitrary. When you differentiate the answer, do you get back the original function?

Comment: Yes, i think it's the same. But why my anwer is different with wolfram, @lord shark?  Why we got the arbitrary constant? Thanks

Comment: ... but the two solutions (yours and W|A) are exactly the same. What's wrong? Don't you understand that $C$ can be any constant?

Comment: Thanks, i think i made a mistake @user202729. i've just understand that the constant isn't always same with the CAS.

Comment: The constant isn't always the same with human solvers either.  But that does not mean one of them is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3x+2}}{1+\sqrt{3x+2}}$

Now, let's try to find the inverse function
$$\begin{align}y&=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3x+2}}{1+\sqrt{3x+2}}\\\dfrac{y+1}{y-1}&=\dfrac{2}{-2\sqrt{3x+2}}\qquad\text{Componendo-Dividendo}\\\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}&=\sqrt{3x+2}\\3x+2&=\dfrac{(y-1)^2}{(y+1)^2}\\x&=\dfrac13\cdot\dfrac{(y-1)^2}{(y+1)^2}-\dfrac23\end{align}$$

Now, integrate by parts
$$\begin{align}\int y\,\mathrm dx&=xy-\int x\,\mathrm dy\\&=xy-\int\dfrac13\cdot\dfrac{(y-1)^2}{(y+1)^2}\,\mathrm dy+\int\dfrac23\,\mathrm dy\\&=xy+\dfrac23y-\dfrac13\int\dfrac{(u-2)^2}{u^2}\,\mathrm du\qquad\qquad\qquad[\because u=y+1]\\&=xy+\dfrac23y-\dfrac13\int\dfrac{u^2-4u+4}{u^2}\mathrm du\\&=xy+\dfrac23y-\dfrac13\int\left(1-\dfrac4u+\dfrac4{u^2}\right)\,\mathrm du\\&=xy+\dfrac23y-\dfrac13y+4\ln|u|+\dfrac4u+C\\&=xy+\dfrac13y+4\ln|y+1|+\dfrac4{y+1}+C\end{align}$$

Substituting the value of $y$ ends the solution.
Don't always worry about your answer to match with a CAS, you can do much better.

Comment: $+1$ for the last sentence (at least) !